# Adding data to Highstock from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am trying to send data to a highstock chart from my rails application. Highstock is a highchart javascript that says it wants chart data in the following format:

```
// Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
// of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
// that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
   data: [[Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ], [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ]]
```

So I can successfully send data from rails to the chart using the following:

```
data:<%= @values.to_json %>
```

but only when @values looks like this:

```
@values = []
@company.values.each do |v|
  @values << v.total_value
end
```

So I know that it is being processed properly here but these values don't have the dates associated with them in order to make them show up in the proper order on the chart. So I tried doing this to get the dates in there with them:

```
@values = []
@company.values.each do |v|
  @values << [v.created_at.to_i*1000, v.total_value]
end
```

I know that the dates are coming through correctly because when I render the chart the date is right but there is only one point, even though the other way (without dates) produced all points, just not with their proper date data.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What does `data:<%= @values.to_json %>` look like after Rails does it's thing?

Comment: Whoops, forgot that I had values with a default_scope order: 'created_at DESC', so I just needed to use @company.values.reverse_each instead of .each, it's happy now

Comment: Thanks anyways Mark, but apparently highcharts needs those values in the correct order of date and will not sort them itself so to anyone else, make sure your data set is sorting the values in the proper date order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to add data detailed above is accurate, however, make sure that data is in order by ascending date otherwise highstock will not know how to graph it properly.